# Не корректная работа wp_head

Tags: wordpress

В шапке сайта вызывается функция `wp_head()`, но она как-то странно работает:
Какие-то плагины подключают шрифты из fonts.googleapis и WP подставляет домен сайта в начало пути. Т.е. должно быть `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?...`, а получается `"http://domain.ru//fonts.googleapis.com/css...`
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить?

Comment: @Hardc0re, спасибо большое! Оформите в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправить можно редактируя код плагина. Вот как нужно подключать стили: `wp_enqueue_style('my-styles', "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-aweso‌​me/4.5.0/css‌​/font-awesome.mi‌​n.css");`

У вас же подключены примерно так:

```
wp_enqueue_style('my-styles', "/fonts.googleapis.com/css...");
```